# Rotate tiled images individually in HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have some code in my game that rotates an icon within its canvas as follows:

```
if (rotate > 0) {
    context.translate(canvasWidth / 2, canvasHeight / 2);
    context.rotate(rotate);
    context.translate(-canvasWidth / 2, -canvasHeight / 2);
}
```

Nothing you haven't seen before. I've also added a function that tiles the icons within a larger canvas like so:

```
var x = 0;
var y = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < totalUnits; i++) {
    context.drawImage(img, x, y);

    if (i != 0 && (i + 1) % level == 0) {
        x = 0;
        y += 72;
    }

    else {
        x += 72;
    }
}
```

Note that the variable `level` can be any integer, and `totalUnits` is its square if it's greater than 1, so for example if I specify `level` as 2, then 4 images are drawn on my canvas, 2 across and 2 down. Note also that my images are always 72x72 pixels, hence the 72 above. Again, nothing particularly exciting.

My difficulty is trying to rotate the images within the canvas such that the individual image is rotated by the value passed in `rotate`, but not the whole canvas itself. I have tried adding the following code with many permutations replacing the above call to `context.drawImage` in the `for` loop, with no luck so far:

```
context.translate(72 / 2, 72 / 2);
context.rotate(rotate);
context.drawImage(img, x, y);
context.rotate(0);
context.translate(-72 / 2, -72 / 2);
```

To help visualise the effect I am trying to achieve, here is what is drawn when rotate is set to 0:

[image]

And here is what I'd like my tiled images on the canvas to look like when rotated by 45 degrees (for example):
[image]

I'd like to point out that I am not trying to rotate the entire canvas - I know how to do that, but it is not the effect I'm trying to achieve as I need the icons to stay in their individual x, y positions. Also, rotating the entire canvas presents cutoff corner challenges.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Easiest way is to overwrite the current transform `ctx.setTransform(scale, 0, 0, scale, x, y); ctx.rotate(rotate); ctx.drawImage(img, -img.width / 2, -img.height/ 2);` Draw image center at `x`, `y` , rotate by `rotate` around `img` center, and includes `scale` 1 is no scale. To reset to default transform `ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0)`

Comment: Thanks Blindman67. I've used your code as suggested and gotten it to work. If you want to post an answer, I'll award you it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to overwrite the current transform

```
ctx.setTransform(scale, 0, 0, scale, x, y); 
ctx.rotate(rotate); 
ctx.drawImage(img, -img.width / 2, -img.height/ 2);
```

Draw image center at `x`, `y`, rotated by `rotate` around `img` center, and scales by `scale`. Scale of 1 is no scale.

To reset to default transform for example before clearing the canvas

```
ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
```

Because under the hood the `ctx.rotate` requires at least 1 sin and 1 cos, 12 temp numbers, then 12 multiplications and 8 additions. If the scaling is uniform (same scale for x and y), it is quicker to use a simplified method to creating the matrix. Note if the scale is always 1 you don't need the scale`

Also when the image loads you can set the point of rotation as properties of the image.

When the image loads set the offset

```
img.offset_x = - img.naturalWidth / 2;  // NOTE I use snake_case for the property names
img.offset_y = - img.naturalHeight / 2; // so that the names will never clash with
                                        // future changes to the standard
```

To render that image

```
const ax = Math.cos(rotate) * scale;
const ay = Math.sin(rotate) * scale;
ctx.setTranform(ax, ay, -ay, ax, x, y);
ctx.drawImage(img, img.offset_x, img.offset_y);
```